# WordPress Blank Screen Issue

Tags: wordpress

I'm running a  WordPress website with a custom template that is showing me a blank screen when I have not viewed the site in a few days. I've cleared the browser cache and I've empited all cache using w3 total cache. Once I cleared the cache,I typed in the URL each time, and it loaded the website perfectly. I did not copy and paste the URL. The URL combinations are listed below;

I've also provided a list of plugins that are currently installed on the website.

1. all in one slideshow v1.3.1
2. ckeditor for wordpress v3.6.2.1
3. contact form 7 v2.2
4. contact form to db extension v2.2.4
5. duplicate post 2.0.2
6. easy picasa v1.1
7. events calendar pro 1.3.3
8. featured image widget v0.2
9. get the image v0.6.2
10. gravity forms v1.6.2
11. gravity forms + custom post types v3
12. gravity forms css ready class selector v1.0.1
13. latest news widget 1.0.1
14. mailchimp v1.2.4
15. members list v3.5.6
16. nextgen gallery v1.7.4
17. page restrict v2.03
18. picasa express x2 v1.5.3
19. really simple captcha
20. registration form widget v1.0
21. search everything v6.7
22. shortcode exec php v1.33
23. si captcha anti-spam v2.7.5
24. sidebar login v2.2.7
25. the excerpt re-loaded v0.3.2
26. w3 total cache 0.9.2.4
27. wordpress https v2.0.4
28. wp custom login logo v1.0
29. wp fade in text news v4.0
30. wpml cms nav v1.2.4
31. wpml multilingual cms v2.3.4
32. wpml string translation v1.2.2
33. wp user registration v2.4

Just wondering if there may be a plugin conflict or maybe a conflict between a plugin and wpml 2.3.4? I've got no issues disabling and re-enabling the plugins one by one, but if I cannot replicate the blank screen issue 100% of the time, disabling/enabling plugins will not be of any use.

I'm also running other websites on my server none of which are showing me this problem. The server I'm running is Ubuntu 10.04 with Apache and MySQL.

Any ideas on what might be causing this issue will be very much apppreciated.

Comment: I had this issue when I tried to remove W3Total cache. I can't remember the solution except that I did a web search for "WordPress blank screen" and eventually stumbled on it. It doesn't sound like you're removing W3, but I wouldn't be surprised if it's somehow still related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all of your suggestions. I somehow managed to repeat the blank screen with no information, which then allowed me to slowly disable and enable the plugins. Found out it had to do with the updating of WPML CMS Nav, WPML String Translation and WMPL Multilingual CMS. Once I updated them, the site worked fine, without the blank screen with no code.

Answer (score 1):

by FTP - temporarly rename your plugin folder to something else (like plugin_new) AND your theme folder and css file (like mytheme.css.old) . that will revert to to the default theme and will disable all plugins . if you do not have default theme - install it. 
If nothing terribly serious has happened (like some code hack) - It will give you access to the admin area to start troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your wp-config.php file:

```
@ini_set('log_errors','On');
@ini_set('display_errors','Off');
@ini_set('error_log','/home/example.com/logs/php_error.log');
```

Right after the following line:

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

Then you can check on the log after the white screen appears, and know for sure what happened.

Comment: Thank you for all of your suggestions. I somehow managed to repeat the blank screen with no information, which then allowed me to slowly disable and enable the plugins. Found out it had to do with the updating of WPML CMS Nav, WPML String Translation and WMPL Multilingual CMS. Once I updated them, the site worked fine, without the blank screen with no code.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone ever runs into this problem with W3 Total Cache, I found a fix for the random blank-page issue: **just turn off ALL of the "Debug Options" under General Settings.**

That fixed it for me after spending countless hours searching for the issue.  Good luck!